# JavaScript for two different elements ID working as same function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using this code (http://technologymantrablog.com/dynamic-combobox-ajax-php-mysql/) for getting country/state/city from my database to php/html selects. It's working perfect in registration form. Everything is fine! The problem is, after user register at the system, he can try to edit your registration/profile. Then, the select for country/state/city appears again. And there is the problem. If I use the same ID's from javascript it won't work. If I try to change the ID's and change the javascript, won't work too. Calling two functions and two different files, won't work too.

**getSelects.php**

```
function getStatus() {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
    xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("inputStatus").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp3.open("GET","includes/getStatus.php",true);
  xmlhttp3.send();
}


function getMotivo(statusID) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
    xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("inputMotivo").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp3.open("GET","includes/getMotivo.php?statusID="+statusID,true);
  xmlhttp3.send();
}


function getComplemento(motivoID) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
    xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp3.readyState==4 && xmlhttp3.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("inputComplemento").innerHTML=xmlhttp3.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp3.open("GET","includes/getComplemento.php?motivoID="+motivoID,true);
  xmlhttp3.send();
}
```

**INCLUDES**

Status:

```
echo '<select onchange="getMotivo(this.value);" class="form-control" name="status" id="status">';

echo 
'<option value="">-- Selecione --</option>
<option value="0">Bloqueado</option>
<option value="1">Ativo</option>';

echo'</select>';
```

Motivo:

```
include("../lib/conexao.php");

$statusID = $_GET['statusID'];

echo '<select onchange="getComplemento(this.value);" class="form-control" name="motivo" id="motivo">';
echo '<option value="" selected>-- Selecione um Motivo --</option>';
$q = "SELECT * FROM motivo WHERE status = '$statusID' AND tipo = 'C' ORDER BY motivo";
if($res = $con->query($q))
{
while($obj = $res->fetch_object())
{
echo'<option value="'. $obj->motivoID .'">'. $obj->motivo .'</option>';
}
}
echo'</select>';
```

Complemento:

```
include("../lib/conexao.php");

$motivoID = $_GET['motivoID'];


if($motivoID == 2 || $motivoID == 4 || $motivoID == 5 || $motivoID == 6 || $motivoID == 8 || $motivoID == 9) {
echo '<label for="complemento">Complemento</label>';
echo '<input type="text" name="complemento" class="form-control" id="complemento" placeholder="Insira o Complemento">';
}
```

header.php:

```
<script>
function init() {
getStatus();
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="init();">
```

I think if I post all the code files here will be very long post. But, with my text in the first paragraph I think I could explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You ought to create some form of generic ajax request function into which you supply parameters at runtime or from within a purpose built function - otherwise you are writing more or less the same code for many different tasks.

Comment: Can you share the form to which you attach these functions?

Comment: Yes, of course. Here is: http://jsfiddle.net/s7Le9725/ thanks for your answer!

Comment: It's strange. I'm trying as many different ways. Just want to have another the same form in another 'modal' and execute the JS to load again the selects.

Comment: Let me see if I have this straight. You use the first dropdown ( populated at page load ) to select items from the db ( using `getStatus.php` ) which in turn builds a new `select` menu that is added to the div `inputStatus`. This new select menu then gets used to query the db ( `getMotivo.php` ) which then builds another `select` menu in the div `inputMotivo`? ie: chained select menus?

Comment: Yes! That's it. And depending on choice of "motivo" the select for "complemento" appears. I'll update my main code with all 'get.php' for you understand better. I took that example from the Internet. I really need something like that or another example too, but I need this chained select menus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94917/discussion-between-rodrigo-brf-and-ramraider).

Comment: Man, I changed everything. I think I got this to work now. Just a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help solve your problem ( hope it does ) but I mentioned using a more or less generic ajax function and using that for the bulk of your work so this is what I meant.

```
function _ajax( url, options ){
    var factories=[
        function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0'); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0'); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0'); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0'); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); }
    ];
    /* Try each factory until we have a winner */
    for( var i=0; i < factories.length; i++ ) {
        try { var req = factories[ i ](); if( req!=null ) { break; } }
        catch( err ) { continue; }
    };

    var method=options.hasOwnProperty('method') ? options.method.toUpperCase() : 'POST';
    var callback=options.hasOwnProperty('callback') ? options.callback :false;

    if( !callback ){
        alert( 'No callback function assigned - a callback is required to handle the response data' );
        return false;
    }

    var headers={
        'Accept': "text/html, application/xml, application/json, text/javascript, "+"*"+"/"+"*"+"; charset=utf-8",
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    };

    /* The main parameters of the request */
    var params=[];
    if( options.hasOwnProperty('params') && typeof( options.params )=='object' ){
        for( var n in options.params ) params.push( n + '=' + options.params[n] );
    }

    /* Additional arguments that can be passed to the callback function */
    var args=options.hasOwnProperty('args') ? options.args : options;

    /* Assign callback to handle response */
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if( req.readyState==4 ) {
           if( req.status==200 ) options.callback.call( this, req.response, args );
           else console.warn( 'Error: '+req.status+' status code returned' );
        }
    }

    /* Execute the request according to desired method: other methods could be added here */
    switch( method ){
        case 'POST':
            req.open( method, url, true );
            for( header in headers ) req.setRequestHeader( header, headers[ header ] );
            req.send( params.join('&') );
        break;
        case 'GET':
            req.open( method, url+'?'+params.join('&'), true );
            for( header in headers ) req.setRequestHeader( header, headers[ header ] );
            req.send( null );
        break;  
    }
}







/*
    example usage:
    --------------
*/
function getStatus() {
    _ajax.call( this, '/includes/getStatus.php',{ callback:cb_ajax, method:'get', args:{ id:'inputStatus' } } );
}
function getMotivo( statusID ) {
    _ajax.call( this, '/includes/getMotivo.php',{ callback:cb_ajax, method:'get', params:{ 'statusID':statusID }, args:{ id:'inputMotivo' } } );
}
function getComplemento( motivoID ) {
    _ajax.call( this, '/includes/getMotivo.php',{ callback:cb_ajax, method:'get', params:{ 'motivoID':motivoID }, args:{ id:'inputComplemento' } } );
}

/* The callback function */
function cb_ajax( r, o ){
    console.info( 'ajax response: %s, args: %s', r, o );
    if( o.hasOwnProperty( 'id' ) && document.getElementById( o.id ) ) document.getElementById( o.id ).innerHTML=r;
}




html form
---------

    <form name='so_test_motivo' method='post' action='/test/target.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <select name='country' onchange='getStatus()'>
            <option value=0 selected> Choose an option
            <option value=1> Test
        </select>

        <select id='inputStatus' name='inputStatus' onchange='getMotivo(this.value)'>
        </select>

        <select id='inputMotivo' name='inputMotivo' onchange='getComplemento(this.value)'>
        </select>   

        <select id='inputComplemento' name='inputComplemento'>
        </select>           
    </form>
```

And for the purposes of the test, the php script `/test/target.php` was simply sending dummy data back like this:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];                
for( $i=0; $i < 50; $i++ ) echo '<option value='.( ( $i+1 ) + $id ).'>Option - '.( ( $i+1 ) + $id ).PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: That one, I just need to replace with my original getSelects.php? That, is not really .php, I typed wrong, it's a .js, lol